# Docker Java 8 Container with Heavy CPU Usage

Tags: java, docker, dockerfile

We are currently dockerize a Java 8 Application and we have a really strange behaviour. Outside of docker, the application use less than 10% of cpu but when we run the application into a container we have 100% of CPU usage for the container.

Inside of the container (with `docker exec -it [container-id] top`), the jar only use 10% of cpu.

We attempt to use other base docker image like `openjdk` but it change nothing.

**Docker File:**

```
FROM anapsix/alpine-java:8
ADD . /producer
WORKDIR /producer
COPY ikb-1.0-SNAPSHOT-producer.jar ikb-1.0-SNAPSHOT-producer.jar
COPY resources/ /resources/
CMD ["java", "-jar", "ikb-1.0-SNAPSHOT-producer.jar"]
```

**We use:**

- **Docker version:** 1.13.1, build 092cba3
- **Docker-compose version:** 1.11.2, build dfed245
- **Server OS:** CentOS

Comment: If you run top on the host while the application is running inside the docker container, does the java process show up as using 100% CPU?

Comment: Yes it's exactly that !

Comment: If you do a `kill -3 <pid>` where `pid` is the java process, you'll get a thread dump.  Does the thread dump look strange? Like it's stuck trying to do networking or I/O?

Comment: I got no output when i execute the `kill -3 pid` it is normal ?

Comment: If you run `docker logs <container>` it should have the output

Comment: I paste the output here : http://pastebin.com/2Y7ZwpXg I don't saw weird infos but i am not used to read this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136495/discussion-between-scott-rankin-and-valentin-michalak).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in our chat, there was a thread in the Java application that was spinning in a tight loop because there was no user input.  Stopping that thread caused the CPU to go back to where it belonged.

Comment: But why this occurs only inside doker?